# Using WebRTC can we access Inbuilt finger print scanner of mobile phone(without using any plugin or App)?

Tags: webrtc, fingerprint

We are trying to capture Biometric fingerprint using WebRTC without installing any plugin or software. Does the web browser have the capability to do it?

Comment: WebRTC is not related to biometrics in any way. It's just roughly an "UDP for browsers".

Comment: Hi @velkan, Does web browser have the capability of getting fingerprint scanner access over phone?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely candidate API in the browser is WebUSB, currently being experimented with in Chrome:

https://wicg.github.io/webusb/

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web

That's assuming that the fingerprint scanner is an USB device.
WebRTC has no API to deal with fingerprint scanners.